# Understanding callq instruction in assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, coredump

I am new to assembly language. During analysis of coredump file i wanted to understand function call at assembly level.

After googling found that callq is the instruction to call a function.

```
  Syntax:
      callq "function Name"
```

However, in core file the syntax is different.

```
          10cd52f:   ff 90 10 02 00 00       callq  *0x210(%rax)
```

Kindly let me know What is this means?

Answer (score 2):

That's an indirect call instruction: it loads a qword of memory from `0x210(%rax)` and calls the function at the address found in that word.  You can tell that it's an indirect call from the `*` in front of the operand.  Refer to the instruction set reference and the GNU assembler manual for details.

Normal relative calls have the syntax you described above:

```
call function
```

note that the `q` suffix can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have gone through this manual http://www.ece.ualberta.ca/~cmpe490/documents/axiom/GNU_Assembler.pdf

Couldn't find required information. Please let me know which section to refer exactly.

I am stuck with one core dump analysis. This is important for me to understand and decode this instruction.

Comment: @user3691131 Here's the [relevant section](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html#i386_002dVariations) from the real GNU as manual.  Note that it too says “absolute” call which is a bit of a misnomer in that all absolute calls marked with a `*` are actually indirect calls, while the normal far absolute call `lcall $segment, $offset` is not marked such.